# Loading URL request for bundle resource in UIWebView doesn't work in jailbroken non-sandboxed app

Tags: iphone, resources, uiwebview, sandbox, nsurl

This code...

```
NSURL *clientURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"client"];
```

...works in the iPhone Simulator but does not appear to be working in a non-sandboxed application deployed to /Applications/ on an actual iPhone.

The application runs after transferring/ldid signing and other functions work but doing this on the device:

```
NSLog(@"Client path: %@", [clientURL path]);
```

returns

```
Client path: (null)
```

So I cannot load the HTML file in the UIWebView.

How can I fix this? Could it be a permissions problem? (the app runs as root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. This was a permissions error.

After I transferred the app to /Applications/ on the device, I used this command:

```
chmod -R 0775 MyAppBundle.app/
```

And now everything works just as it should.